# Load data of specific user from MySQL DB into HTML textfields using PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, mysql

I have a form in which people have to type their ID, based on the ID the corresponding data from the database is loaded into text fields on the same page. People can alter the data and update the database.

To load the data I use the following Javascript code:

```
function btn_load_Click(){
    if(window.XMLHttpRequest){
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        }
    else {
        xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function(){
        if(xmlhttp.readyState==4&& xmlhttp.status==200){
            document.getElementById("perDATA").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
            }
        }
    xmlhttp.open("POST","Load.php",true);
    xmlhttp.send();

    document.getElementById('txtItem1').value = document.getElementById('hid-item1').value;
    document.getElementById('txtItem2').value = document.getElementById('hid-item2').value;
}
```

The PHP:

```
$host = "localhost";
$user = "username";
$password = "password";
$database = "database";

$connection = mysqli_connect($host,$user,$password,$database) or die ("connection to server failed");
mysqli_select_db($connection,$database) or die ("couldn’t select database");
$player = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection,$_POST['txtUser']);
$item1 = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection,$_POST['txtItem1']);
$item2 = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection,$_POST['txtItem2']);

$query = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE userId=$player";
$result = mysqli_query($connection,$query)
or die ("couldn’t execute update query: ".mysqli_error($connection));
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);

echo "<input type='hidden' id='hid-item1' value='".$row['item1']."'>";
echo "<input type='hidden' id='hid-item2' value='".$row['item2']."'>";
mysqli_close($connection);

?>
```

The HTML form:

```
<body>
   <form id="form1" action="http://www.something.com/TestScript1.php" method="post" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded">

    <div>
    <button type="submit" id="submit" value="Submit" title="SAVE">SAVE</button>
    </div>
    <div>
        <input id="txtUser" name="txtUser" type="text" />
        <input id="txtItem1" name="txtItem1" type="text" />
        <input id="txtItem2" name="txtItem2" type="text" />
    </div>

</form>
<div id="perDATA" name="perDATA"></div>
</body>
```

The issue: I use the Javascript to load the data in hidden fields and then copy them to the right text field. When I use a fixed ID instead of `$player` in the PHP script, it works just fine. However passing the ID to `$player` seems to be a problem. So, what I want is when people enter their ID en click LOAD, their ID value is send to the `$player` variable in the PHP script. The PHP script fetches the required data of that user from the database, echoes the hidden fields containing the data. And subsequently the data from the hidden fields is copied to the right text fields. All of this should happen without leaving the current page.

Comment: You really should learn about [prepared](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) statements for [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php).

Comment: Thank you Jay for the input. Will use of prepared statements fix my issue or is it just "better practice" for writing php?